# Orientation Variable, Protected Key in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mobile

I developed a image tool for multiple uploads, rotate and resize images. In this tool i used a variable called "orientation" and in any browser web works (this variable set the orientation of a image "0,1,2,3" = "0,90,180,270").

As i told before everything works. But i noticed that on some mobile device (not all) the variable "orientation" is used by the device. In dev tool if i print the "orientation" variable i get the orientation of device, so when i use and set this variable i can't override it and my application breaks.

Obviously the solution is change the variable name but i would like to know if "orientation" is a protected key or something strange.

I not found anything about this issue on Google.

Comment: If you've used a local variable `var orientation`, this shouldn't be a problem. You'll only have trouble if you're using global variables.

Comment: Yeah sure, sorry for the lack in my question. Obviously is a global variable, and i need to keep it global.

Comment: Anyway, i resolved the issue changed the variable name. Orientation is a protected variable and in some devices (i don't know why not on all) not works.